# Скролл страницы на гугл панорамах

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Здравствуйте!
При скролле страниц когда курсор мыши попадает на область гугл панорамы в iframe, скролл страницы останавливается. Если убрать курсор мыши с панорамы, то скролл работает. Как сделать что бы скролл страницы всегда работал?
Настройки панорамы:

```
function initialize() {

var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 50;
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row_kv["geo_coords"]; ?>);
streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE,         function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {

   var panorama = new      google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), {
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row_kv["geo_coords"]; ?>),
   visible: true,
   scrollwheel: false,
   disableDefaultUI: true,
   panControl:true,
   zoomControl:true,
   linksControl:true,
   fullscreenControl:true,
   zoom: 1
    });

    } else {

 document.getElementById("panorama").style.display = "none";

    }
});
  }
initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо добавить `scrollwheel: false`, чтобы игнорировать скролл

Comment: scrollwheel: false - уже стоит в настройках, выключает маштабирование скроллом, на прокрутку страницы никак не влияет

Comment: @ДмитрийПортнов, а можно код панорамы?

Comment: Добавил код в описание вопроса

Comment: @ДмитрийПортнов, видимо встроенного решения от гугла нет, но есть предложение поверх панорамы наложить полупрозрачный div с текстом что-то вроде "Нажмите, чтобы посмотреть", который при скролле не будет давать панораме его блокировать, а при нажатии div пропадает и можно пользоваться панорамой